# C++ graphic interface frameworks/libraries

Tags: c++, interface, graphic

I need to program a game, it's a card game actually, and I must make it with graphic interface, but I don´t know about C++ graphic interface libraries.

Is there something for C++ similar to Python's Tkinter or Pygame (I don´t know if there are others).

If there are libs, are they suited for building a simple card game?

Comment: What is your operating system and toolchain?

Comment: Qt seems to be the most popular, then there's wxWidgets and GTK+. And lots and lots of other things if you bothered to look.

Comment: @SteveTownsend my OS is W8, and I really don't know about my toolchain, I work with NetBeans, if this is relevant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common cross-platform GUI toolkit is [Qt](http://qt-project.org), I'd go with that for any C++ GUI application. Especially easy on Linux, all distros have packages for it, but Windows has binary installers too for different compilers.

You can use Netbeans, but I'd really go with Qt Creator for Qt programming.

For a card game with Qt, QGraphicsView is probably easiest, if you want animated card movement etc. For a more static UI, QWidget based one would be very easy. For a modern visually rich UI, QML (but then GUI part is not C++) would work very well.

Achilles heel of Qt for game development is real-time game sound effects, but you can mix Windows-specific sound stuff easily if you do not care about cross platform stuff, and card games don't need much there anyway, if anything. Also, I think Qt5 may actually have improvements for sound, making pure Qt good enough for games.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a game, you may consider [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/)

Fun fact: pygame is backed by SDL.

BTW, if you want to have GUI controls in your game( http://www.tayloredge.com/utilities/vbapps/gui.GIF ) , you will need a GUI library. Otherwise, a game library, like SDL, is more suitable for you.